# Sheet has blank cell instead of result from database

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to extract values from a mysql database into a google sheet. Here's what I have so far the script editor:

```
// Replace the variables in this block with real values.
var address = 'some.rds.amazonaws.com';
var user = 'abc';
var userPwd = '123';
var db = 'db';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:mysql://' + address + '/' + db;

function readFromTable(member) {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT fullname FROM member WHERE id_member = 12345; ' );
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + '\t';
    }
    Logger.log(rowString)
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

If I run it from the script editor the log gives

```
[15-06-11 14:04:01:870 BST] Bob Brett   
[15-06-11 14:04:01:873 BST] Time elapsed: 121.0ms
```

However, in a sheet if I insert =readFromTable() gives a blank cell and no errors.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method does not return anything. The cell will display the return value of the function, not the log. Add a return statement at the end of the function and try again.

Comment: That was it. Wondering why google hasn't included this in the examples. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Hasn't include _what_ in _which_ examples? There are scads of examples, not all require `return`.